# Dynamodb get item is erroring out

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

using javascript aws sdk

my table definition is as follows:

```
  resources:
  Resources:
    ImagesTable:
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: "deviceId"
            AttributeType: "S"
          - AttributeName: "timeStamp"
            AttributeType: "N"
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: "deviceId"
            KeyType: "HASH"
          - AttributeName: "timeStamp"
            KeyType: "RANGE"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.settings.${self:custom.myStage}.ITEMS_DYNAMODB_TABLE}
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
```

I try to run a query and get all devices that match a string.

my params object is

```
        const params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.GetItemInput = {
          TableName: eventLogTable,
          Key: {deviceId: 'device12345'}
        };
```

my call is

```
return this.client.get(params).promise()
        .then(result => {
            return result;
        });
```

in the log files, I see the following error:

```
2019-06-21T17:23:27.878Z    cc865442-8604-4f5c-8099-72eba87d9b2b    query params right before going in { TableName: 'sls-basic-operations-items-dev',
Key: { deviceId: 'device12345' } }
2019-06-21T17:23:27.904Z    cc865442-8604-4f5c-8099-72eba87d9b2b    { ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Not obvious what my mistake is?
Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what went wrong here is that you are using dynamodb client Get operation while only specifying the hash key. Since your table has a range key(sort key) ,you should also specify that in the Getitem request
If you only want to search for the records using the hash key them you should use the Query operation.
params = {
      TableName: 'eventLogTable',
      KeyConditionExpression: '#deviceId = :deviceId'
  };
DynamoDB.DocumentClient.query
(params,

Comment: client.get takes a DynamoDB.DocumentClient.GetItemInput parameter and it does not have  a KeyConditionExpression field. Based on that I am not seeing how I can add KeyConditionExpression field to the params object. I can see a similar code to mine in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html

Comment: Its simple, just provide the timestamp key value pair in the Key section.ie:                     Key: {deviceId: 'device12345',timestamp:134282}

Comment: the point is I don't have a time stamp, I am query for items for a specific deviceId, timeStamp can be anything

Comment: Yes that's why I specifically asked you to use the Query operation which requires only the hashkey. Look into that.